# Is there a way to remove a character from multiple file names

Tags: command-line, scripts, filename

I have a client that gave me an ancient PowerMac G4 with a non-booting OS and dying hard drive to retrieve files from. I've been working on that all day and have his files successfully retrieved, but his current modern PC is a Windows desktop and many of the filenames on his old machine have an asterix (`*`) or a colon (`:`) in the name for some reason...

The issue is that Windows does not allow those characters in filenames. Is there a way I can run a Terminal command or script or some such on my Linux laptop to batch remove those characters from his files so he can copy them to his Windows desktop rather than having to manually rename 500 things...?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the perl-based `rename` command, with perl's built-in `tr` (transliterate) in place of the more commonly use `s` (substitute).

Ex given

```
$ ls *[:*]*
'a::b*:c'   bar:bam  'foo*baz'
```

then

```
$ rename -n 'tr/:*/-_/' *
rename(a::b*:c, a--b_-c)
rename(bar:bam, bar-bam)
rename(foo*baz, foo_baz)
```

Answer (score 1):

I learned about the amazingly handy package called [`detox`](http://detox.sourceforge.net/), which removes problematic characters from all files in a certain directory. Very useful!

To install it, you can download the tar.gz file from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/detox/files/detox/1.2.0/), extract it,  `cd` into the extracted directory and run:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

See the [README](http://detox.sourceforge.net/readme.html) for more info regarding the package's compilation.

Usage example from the package's webpage:

> ```
> $ ls
> Future Crew - Skaven - 2nd Reality.s3m
> $ detox -v .
> Scanning: .
> ./Future Crew - Skaven - 2nd Reality.s3m -> ./Future_Crew-Skaven-2nd_Reality.s3m
> $ ls
> Future_Crew-Skaven-2nd_Reality.s3m
> ```

For more info on how to use it, see the [`detox` manpage](http://detox.sourceforge.net/detox.1.html).

<sub>Answer expanded from [OP's answer in the question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1250367/4).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on an Ubuntu machine using Bash:

1. Make a list of bad filenames in a directory, using the `ls` command, and name the file list `badnames`. First change default directory to the directory containing the bad files:

   ```
   cd somedirectory
   ls > badnames
   ```
2. Use `tr` to change the bad character to a good character (for example a random choice not guaranteed to be Windows compatible: `:` to `.` and `*` to `-`), putting the good names into a file named `goodnames`:

   ```
   cat badnames | tr ":*" ".-" > goodnames
   ```
3. Paste the two files toghether (check for duplicates, etc.):

   ```
   paste badnames goodnames > pairednames
   ```
4. Add the command `mv` to the start of each line in `pairednames`.
5. Run the renames:

   ```
   bash pairednames
   ```

---

It's just a little harder if you have the `badfiles` in a directory structure instead of all in one directory. From the top, use the `find` command instead of `ls`.